# Icomoon : how to avoid duplicate index (different icon with same content id)?

Tags: css, icomoon

I have a website with an icomoon.css file previously insered by someone else.
Now I added my own icomoon css, renamed icomoon2.
The problem is that now I have some icons with the same content id, ex:
content: "\e976"; on both css files point to 2 different icons.
So only one icon is displayd.

I don't have the original json file and I need both the icons.

I think I should change the content id in the css file, and then change accordingly in the .eot .svg  .tiff .woff  files right?

Comment: Use the online Icomoon app, change it there and re-export your version. Don't do manual hacks in generated files, nothing good can result from that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rene van der Lende already pointed out: re-compiling your icon font is probably the best solution.

Import the **svg** font file in icomoon app (icomoon uses svg font files internally for importing icons)

#### Alternative: load both font families and add some overriding rules in css

You will need two `@font-face` rules:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoonNew';
  src: url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}

.icon-share:before {
  content: "\e900";
}

.icon-missing:before {
  font-family: 'icomoonNew'!important;
  content: "\e90b";
}
```

Comment: Thak you, I didn't know you can import svg in icomoon! I thought you need the json file.  Anyway also the other solution is smart, thank you.